# Modernizr.geolocation is always true

Tags: modernizr

I have a Modernizr check for geolocation support. I noticed it wasn't working as expected so I put in some logs to see what was happening. It seems that it is alerting true whether geolocation is enabled in the browser or not. I know I'm disabling geolocation in my browser correctly because it works as expected for Modernizr.geolocation demos I've found online.

```
    //Check for geolocation support; hide "use my location" button if unsupported
    if (Modernizr.geolocation) { 
        console.log('true');
        //App.locateInit();
    } else {
        console.log('false');
        //$('#geo-container').css('display','none');
    }
```

I'm calling the custom Modernizr script with the geolocation piece. Any ideas as to what could be causing this? Please let me know what to look for or what other info you may need, I'm very new to Modernizr.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which browser? Apparently your browser doesn't remove the API when its disabled, which means its impossible to detect the disabling. :(

Comment: Am I misunderstanding how the Modernizr detection works? I assume it only detects whether or not your browser supports geolocation, NOT whether or not you have it disabled?

Comment: It depends on how it's implemented. The correct way for Firefox to support this is if you, as a user, disable geolocation, then `navigator.geolocation` should be undefined. If this doesn't happen, they give us a false positive result which we cannot detect

Comment: I've filed a ticket for Mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688158

Comment: I'm seeing reports this is still a bug in Firefox on Windows. Can anyone confirm? I didn't see that the ticket Paul Irish reported has been addressed, but it's hard to tell from those bug report displays. Thanks.

Comment: And I just confirmed that it's still a bug in Firefox 10.0.1 on Mac.  Anyone got a workaround?